# Conflict JQUERY / Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing an extension but there is a conflict with jquery, it works for my code but blocks the jquery of other extensions ...
I have watched all the posts on this subject, 2 months that I block ...
Here is my code:

```
function carla_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'carla_query', plugins_url('js/jq.min.js', __FILE__), array());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'carla_query' );
    wp_enqueue_script('carla-script', plugins_url('js/bootstrap.min.js', 
    __FILE__));
}

carla_script();
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carla_script' );
```

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to load jquery again, possibly a different version and named **jq.min.js**.

By default Wordpress is already going to load jquery for you, so why not remove **carla-query** and just leave **carla-script**?